# useEffect hook: If a value updates, is it guaranteed that the cleanup function runs synchronously right before its effect function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The return value of the `useEffect` callback is an effect cleanup function which is called before the effect callback and before the component unmounts.

I'm asking myself whether it can be guarranteed that the cleanup function will synchronously be called right before its corresponding effect callback function? Given that the cleanup function is itself synchronous of course.

**Example**: In this simple component here the string `"cleanup"` is indeed logged before `"effect"` each time you hit the `Increment` button.

```
export default function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  console.log("App: render");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("effect");
    return () => console.log("cleanup");
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <>
      <h2>useEffect</h2>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Increment</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

But can this order always be guaranteed? In fact: Can you be sure that the cleanup code runs directly before the corresponding effect function?

Or is there perhaps any async behavior involved in the cleanup function of `useEffect`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not in general. You can't generally guarantee that the `cleanup` function of a given hook will run right before its corresponding effect function.

But that's not the case because of any hidden async behavior involved (unless you explicitly create an async cleanup function.

In your code example you can indeed guarantee the `cleanup` function running directly before the `effect` function in case the component gets updated. But that's just because you only have a single component with a single `useEffect` function.

If you have several `useEffect` hooks in one component or other child components with `useEffect` hooks, all `cleanup` functions of all components are run before all `effect` functions of all `useEffect` hooks are run:

[image: use effect execution order]

Ass @keith mentioned in his comment the order of execution is:

> render, render, cleanup, cleanup, effect, effect

And not

> render, render, cleanup, effect, cleanup, effect

In [this CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/useeffect-order-of-cleanup-and-effect-functions-r2utf?file=/src/App.js) you see exactly that and can play around with it.

Comment: At the component level, it will indeed be the case.  The OP did ask -> `its corresponding effect callback function`..  But a good answer anyway, as what your saying is   `render,render,cleanup,cleanup,effect,effect.`   And not `render,render,cleanup,effect,cleanup,effect`..

Comment: @Keith But also "at the component level" the cleanup won't run directly before its corresponding effect callback function in case you have more than one useEffect hook with the same dependency array.

Comment: I think what your calling corresponding is different to mine,  A useEffect & it's corresponding cleanup will be always call it's cleanup before it's next iteration of useEffect.  Because a totally unrelated cleanup is also called on another useEffect should really never be an issue.   Regardless of the logic here, at this low level, it's certainly something you shouldn't rely on, as it may change.  Who knows, React might go the `render, render, cleanup, effect, cleanup, effect`, and if you relied on the current implementation, it's not going to be pretty.

Comment: Saying the above, it is an interesting observation.  And if your investigation is purely curiosity, that's fine, but if it's to influence some form of programming logic, I would say be very careful here.